# Is there a way in Laravel to add/remove multiple indexes with a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a bit of code in a Laravel migration (MySQL database) that looks like this:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('column1');
    $table->index('column2');
    $table->index('column3');
});
```

The end result of running this migration is fine. The problem is that it's very slow, because when I watch MySQL's `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, Laravel is doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `column1_index` (`column1`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `column2_index` (`column2`);
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD INDEX `column3_index` (`column3`);
```

I am interested in the speed benefits of having indexes added to a table using this style of query:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
    ADD INDEX `column1_index` (`column1`),
    ADD INDEX `column2_index` (`column2`),
    ADD INDEX `column3_index` (`column3`);
```

If I manually run the latter, it is about 3x faster than running the former. For running these queries on production, this is extremely valuable.

Edit: To clarify, I'm not looking for a composite key for those three columns. I'm not looking for `$table->index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']);` I'm looking for a functionally identical result of the code I already have, but the speed benefits of combining the three queries into one.

Is there a way to have Laravel add/remove multiple indexes in a single query? If not, I may just need to run a "raw" query.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way.  Laravel's schema functions are useful for compatibility with different database formats but may not be the most efficient.  Just write comparable raw sql for the production server:

```
if (config('app.env') === 'production') {
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users`
    ADD INDEX `column1_index` (`column1`),
    ADD INDEX `column2_index` (`column2`),
    ADD INDEX `column3_index` (`column3`);');
}
else {
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('column1');
        $table->index('column2');
        $table->index('column3');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's too late, this works well for me.

```
namespace Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

trait MigrationIndex
{
    public function indexIfNotExist($tableName, $columns)
    {
        Schema::table($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableName, $columns) {
            $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
            $doctrineTable = $sm->introspectTable($tableName);
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $indexName = $tableName . '_' . $column . '_' . 'index';
                if (!$doctrineTable->hasIndex($indexName)) {
                    $table->index($column, $indexName);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public function dropIndexIfExist($tableName, $columns)
    {
        Schema::table($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) use ($tableName, $columns) {
            $sm = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager();
            $doctrineTable = $sm->introspectTable($tableName);
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $indexName = $tableName . '_' . $column . '_' . 'index';
                if ($doctrineTable->hasIndex($indexName)) {
                    $table->dropIndex($indexName);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In migrate file

```
class AddIndex extends Migration
{
    use MigrationIndex;

    public function up()
    {
        $this->indexIfNotExist('tableName', [
            'column1',
            'column2',
            'column3'
        ]);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropIndexIfExist('tableName', [
            'column1',
            'column2',
            'column3'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass an array of columns to `index()` method

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3']);
});
```

Comment: This would create a composite key on those three columns, which is not what I'm looking for. I want three separate indexes on three separate columns, but I also want the speed benefits of adding all the indexes in one query instead of in three separate queries.